# Database for Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight

Tags: c#, sql, sqlite, sql-server-ce, windows-phone-8.1

Any good recommendation of database for me to develop in the Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight? There're SQLite, SQL Server CE 4.0. But I heard some of them still not compatible with the Windows Phone 8.1, so which database I can use for Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight? And there're any tutorial for me to do the database for the Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight? Anyone can help me? Please...

Answer (score 1):

If you plan to update your project to universal apps, you should use SQLite because SQL Server CE is not supported in WinRT. Whereas SQLite is supported for both Windows Phone 8.1 and Windows 8.1.

Comment: But the problem is I created the project as the Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight instead of the Universal apps...So which 1 is better for me?

Comment: If you do not plan to update your project to universal apps in the future, I think that SQL Server CE is better. Otherwise, you shoud use SQLite.

Comment: So all the version of SQL Server CE compatible with the Windwos Phone 8.1? Any tutorial of it for me? =)

Comment: Tuturials: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202860(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: And here is a sample : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202876%28v=vs.105%29.aspx

Comment: @ErikEJ Does Local Database same as the SQLite and SQL Server CE?? What is the differences of them?

Answer (score -1):

Old question, but I couldn't spare my self.

Don't use sql in WP8(is it even allowed?) and client applications overall, it's bad architechture, really bad and dangerous. 
Databases belongs on backends that host Webservices, like forinstance WCF with JSON and/or SOAP. It also lets the backend to the heavy db lifting.

Use Object Relation Models or Entitites for your data you get from the backend, and let the backend do all db magic independent off db type. It makes it so much easier for your client code as well, as you can just bind to these datamodels.

[NHibernate](https://www.nuget.org/packages/nhibernate) is a pretty good provider, and I would reccomend you to have a look at it.

Cheers

Stian